# Rxjs: Merge two streams with one stream that depends of another

Tags: javascript, angular, stream, rxjs

I have a stream that calls a service that returns a stream that needs the info of the original stream for the request.

```
this.messages$ = this.selectedChat$
.switchMap(chat => this.chatService.subscribeMessages(chat.room))
.map(messages) =>
  messages.map((message: any) => {
    //Here need add information of the chat object
    return message;
  })
);
```

All operators that I see that can merge the streams and separate them later (like `combineLatest`) receive parameters, therefore, I can´t use the original stream info to call the service that generates the other stream, and I would not like to use subscribe on the original stream and return a new stream inside the subscribe because it's a little messy code.

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `selector function` in the `switchMap` operation:

```
this.messages$ = this.selectedChat$
.switchMap(chat => this.chatService.subscribeMessages(chat.room), 
(chat,messages)=>({chat,messages})) // create a new object, using the inner observable and the mapped one
.map(data =>
  data.messages.map((message: any) => {
    // Here data.chat has the chat information
    return message;
  })
);
```

For more information about the `switchMap` operator check [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

Comment: Best solution i think, keeps the code readable and flat. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered, but I'm curious - looks to me like a mix-up with the brackets and a missing return.

Original:

```js
this.messages$ = this.selectedChat$
.switchMap(chat => this.chatService.subscribeMessages(chat.room))
.map(messages) =>
  messages.map((message: any) => {
    //Here need add information of the chat object
    return message;
  })
);
```

This looks like a typo `.map(messages) =>`.

I tried this

```js
const selectedChat$ = Observable.of({ room: '1', chatter: 'me', chattee: 'you' })
const subscribeMessages = (room) => Observable.of(['msg1', 'msg2'])

const messages$ = selectedChat$
  .switchMap(chat => subscribeMessages(chat.room)
    .map(messages => {
      return messages.map(message => {
        //Here need add information of the chat object
        return [message, chat];
      })
    })
  )

messages$.subscribe(console.log)
```

and got a result with chat in it, after proper closure is applied.

Do I have the wrong shape for test observables, or misunderstood the requirement?

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly, but, in my personal opinion, it's more readable not to nest the chain on several levels

Comment: It has exactly the same number of nesting levels as the accepted answer, the difference is only in the indentation.

Comment: At the first view I cannot see if the map is on the principal stream or on the subscribedMessages. But it's only my personal opinion, maybe other people prefers this solution.

Comment: Sure, fair enough - everyone has a preferred layout. Actually, I usually do more indentation, for example `subscribeMessages(chat.room)` would be on the it's own line and everything following indented even more.

Comment: I guess it's just important to show this can be done without use of `selector function`, and that `chat` is captured by closure, which is a useful concept to know about.

Comment: It doesnt have the same level of nesting. The map(messages) is nested in the switchMap operator. I personally preffer to keep the operations simple and work on the main stream. But its still great that you show this other option, as this is a solution too.

Comment: @Jota - I count 4 levels each one. switchMap/map/map/return. It's the same either solution, but harder to see with your's due to the lack of indenting :).

Comment: Apologies, I see the extra bracket on line 3, closing the switchMap.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
this.messages$ = this.selectedChat$
.switchMap(chat => {
// chat still within the scope
  return this.chatService.subscribeMessages(chat.room))
    .map(messages) =>
       messages.map((message: any) => {
       //Here need add information of the chat object
       return message;
     })
});
```

if you insist on passing down the variable you can try

```
this.messages$ = this.selectedChat$
.switchMap(chat =>this.chatService.subscribeMessages(chat.room).combineLatest(Observable.of(chat)))
    .map([messages,chat]) =>
       messages.map((message: any) => {
       //Here need add information of the chat object
       return message;
     })
});
```

You can also setup a global variable store with use of Behaviour subject, if there are too many global value needed